# Detect if HTTP method (POST, GET) in jQuery.ajaxComplete()

Tags: ajax, http, jquery

In a `jQuery.ajaxComplete()` how can I detect the HTTP method, specifically a GET or a POST?

I've tried reading the jQuery documentation and searching around and I can't seem to find much documentation of the 3 objects passed to the function handler inside

```
jQuery(element).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `settings` object in the AJAX callback is the settings object that was passed into the AJAX call.  You can therefore look for the `type` property on it to see whether it was GET or POST:

```
jQuery(element).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
    alert(settings.type);
});
```

The settings that you can retrieve in this manner are the same as those that you can set with the [`$.ajax` constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).