# show div only on POST requests via ajax global events

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have ajax global events to show overlay on every ajax hit on document, it look somthing like:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (e, jqXHR) {
    //show the loading div here
    $('#DivProgressBar').show(); //if ajax is Post only 
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, jqXHR) {
    //remove the div here
    $('#DivProgressBar').hide(); //if ajax is Post only 
});
```

Now i want that this overlay should only work for post requests only and not for get requests.
Can i modify my current jquery code to achive this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(element).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
    alert(settings.type);
});
```

Found that in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6710284/643761

Comment: well this should be in comment, but thanks for answer :)

Comment: Hopefully it has helped you get to the answer :-D

Answer (score 1):

you may use `$(document).ajaxSetup({type: 'POST'});` for only post request.