# Identify HTTP verb from an HTTP request error response in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, http-verbs

I called a **HTTP** request from my **Angular** app, it failed and I got an error response. But, from the response, I am not able to identify the **HTTP verb** of the **API** that was called.

Is there any way to identify the HTTP verb from an error response?

Here I am attaching my error response.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if HTTP method (POST, GET) in jQuery.ajaxComplete()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710252/detect-if-http-method-post-get-in-jquery-ajaxcomplete)

Comment: Actually, in my case it is not an AJAX call. It is a HTTP call from Angular.

Comment: Then why are you using JQuery ? using JQuery with Angular is an anti-pattern ... And it's easier to find the HTTP method with Angular.

Comment: I have a global error handling module. So, I am throwing the error from service and catching from error module. So, from there I need to identify the HTTP verb.

Comment: So you don't need Jquery, right ?

Comment: ok, then can you tell me how to do that in Angular

Comment: He doesn't use JQuery, the screenshoted error response is what returned by the `HttpClient` so it's from Angular.

Comment: I have no access to imgur @NoNameProvided, I was asking because of that reason. Arun, I'm on it !

Answer (score 2):

to get the HTTP verb, you will need to use interceptors and the new `HttpClient`.

To use interceptors, please refer to **[the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)**.

Here is the function of the interceptor :

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  console.log(req.method); // shows the verb
  return next
    .handle(req);
}
```

So if you want to handle the errors, use an interceptor to do that !